# GetPosition returns wrong value with Image element

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I write WPF app. There is `Image` element and i defined `MouseDown` event.

```
private void firstImagePanel_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point x = e.GetPosition(firstImagePanel);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X:\t{0}\nY:\t{1}",x.X/image.PixelWidth, x.Y/image.PixelHeight));
    }
```

`image` - is the source for this panel.
When I click somewhere on the image, `MessageBox.Show()` writes wrong position. 
For example, when i click on the center, it writes:

`X: 0.25 
Y: 0.25`

I don't know where the mistake is.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Blending.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="openFirstImage" Content="Open 1st image" Padding="10" Margin="0 10 0 0" Click="openFirstButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="dragAndDrop"  Content="Drag and Drop" Padding="10" Margin="10 10 0 0" Click="dragAndDrop_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="openSecondImage" Content="Open 2nd image" Padding="10" Margin="0 10 0 0" Click="openSecondImage_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="blend"  Content="Blend" Padding="10" Margin="10 10 0 0" Click="blend_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Image  x:Name="firstImagePanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,0" MouseDown="firstImagePanel_MouseDown_1" />
    <Image  x:Name="secondImagePanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3"/>
</Grid>
```

I noticed, that with different pictures, position has different proportions.

Comment: Post your xaml too. Are you expecting it to write 0.5?

Comment: @Chris Yes. I added XAML.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Image x:Name="firstImagePanel"
       Source="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjcwNzczNDQ0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTE0NzA0MQ@@._V1_SX214_AL_.jpg"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       MouseDown="FirstImagePanel_OnMouseDown" />
```

and the event handler:

```
Point x = e.GetPosition(firstImagePanel);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X:\t{0}\nY:\t{1}", 

    x.X / firstImagePanel.ActualWidth, 
    x.Y / firstImagePanel.ActualHeight));
```

The problem might be that you have margin, or your `PixelWidth` is not equal to the picture displayed on the screen.

My example should give you 0.5, 0.5, if you click to center.